# Displays empty list in jade with node js and sql server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, pug

Can't see any output in jade in browser. What am I doing wrong?

server2.js file

```
     var express = require('express');
     var app = express();

     app.set("view engine","jade")

     app.get('/', function (req, res) {


var sql = require("mssql");

var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'test21',
    server: 'test\\SQL2008',
    database: 'testdb2'
};

//sql.connect(config, function (err) {

     new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {

   //if (err) console.log(err);

    var request = new sql.Request();
   // request.query('select * from test', function (err, recordset) {

        return pool.request().query("SELECT * FROM test", function (err, recordset) {     
        if (err) 
            console.log(err)
        else
            if (err) 
                console.log(err)
            else
                res.render('StudentList', { studentList: recordset });
            });
    });
});
    var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
console.log('Server is running..');
```

});

StudentList.jade file created in the views folder

```
doctype html
html
head
title=title
body
    h1 Student List 
    ul
        each item in studentList
            li=item.StudentName
```

This is what the output is:

Student List:

### -

### -

### -

Table structure:
Table Name: Test
Column name: Name 
Values: test
        test 2

Comment: Is there something called "StudentName" in your database?

Comment: it is the column name. what it should be?